# Tkinter Toplevel : Destroy window when not focused

Tags: python, tkinter, focus, destroy, toplevel

I have a `Toplevel` widget that I want to destroy whenever the user clicks out of the window. I tried finding solutions on the Internet, but there seems to be no article discussing about this topic.

How can I achieve this. Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like that :
fen is your toplevel

```
fen.bind("<FocusOut>", fen.quit)
```

Comment: `<FocusOut>` seems to work, but not very responsive when I click inside the main window (Only works if I click outside). Any other ways ?

Comment: You can add a <FocusIn> then

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and fixed it. The following example works fine.
It displays a Toplevel window on top of the main window, as a customized config menu.
Whenever the user clicks somewhere else, the config menu disappears.

Warning: Don't use .transient(parent) on the Toplevel window, otherwise, the symptom that you described happens: when clicking on the main window, the menu does not disappear. You can try in the example below to uncomment the "self.transient(parent)" line to reproduce your issue.

Example:

```
import Tix


class MainWindow(Tix.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Init
        self.parent = parent
        Tix.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)
        w = Tix.Button(self, text="Config menu", command=self.openMenu)
        w.pack()

    def openMenu(self):
        configWindow = ConfigWindow(self)
        configWindow.focus_set()


class ConfigWindow(Tix.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Init
        self.parent = parent
        Tix.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        # If you uncomment this line it reproduces the issue you described
        #self.transient(parent)
        # Hides the window while it is being configured
        self.withdraw()
        # Position the menu under the mouse
        x = self.parent.winfo_pointerx()
        y = self.parent.winfo_pointery()
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        # Configure the window without borders
        self.update_idletasks() # Mandatory for .overrideredirect() method
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        # Binding to close the menu if user does something else
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.close)  # User focus on another window
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.close)    # User press Escape
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        # The configuration items
        w = Tix.Checkbutton(self, text="Config item")
        w.pack()
        # Show the window
        self.deiconify()


    def close(self, event=None):
        self.parent.focus_set()
        self.destroy()


tixRoot = Tix.Tk()
tixRoot.withdraw()
app = MainWindow(tixRoot)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work for me when I had 2 `<tkinter.Entry>`s but I found this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

focus = 0

def focus_in(event):
    global focus
    focus += 1

def focus_out(event):
    global focus
    focus -= 1
    if focus == 0:
        root.destroy()

root = tk.Toplevel()
root.bind("<FocusIn>", focus_in)
root.bind("<FocusOut>", focus_out)
root.mainloop()
```

It has a counter for the number of times the window is focused. It destroys the window when the counter reaches 0.